# strange behavior saving a file with vim on Windows in a folder that requires elevated permission

Tags: vim

I'm editing the apache2.conf configuration file under the 'C:\Program Files...' folder. This folder requires elevated permission ("Start program as administrator") for writing to anywhere on this folder.

Opening the file by mistake with vim without elevation - didn't show any warning. Moreover, I was able to save the file (':wq') just fine without any warning. Opening the file again with vim - showed me the modified file. However - no changes in the behavior of Apache (of course).

Trying to open the file with Notepad - show me the file was not modified.

Then, trying to open the file with vim from an elevated shell - I got the original file (just like notepad), but this time, I was able to edit the file, and save it.

I know have two versions of the file. The real file (shown by notepad, elevated shell, just 'type' and seen by apache httpd), and the file I edited and saved from an unelevated shell - stored somewhere (where???).

This is very uncomfortable, as sometime I open this file by mistake from a regular shell (even just for read).

What is going on? How do I exit this state?

Comment: Maybe there's some saved buffer (files ending with `~` or `.swp` or `.swo`) that is loaded in Vim. Try looking in the directory defined by the vim variable `backupdir` (`:set backupdir?` in _normal mode_ to display its value) for such file.

Comment: Or try `:echo expand('%:p')` after editing the file from normal and privileged shells.

Answer (score 2):

I was hit by a Windows feature called "Virtual Store". Underneath the unaware application (that is, vim in this case), the OS running in compatibility mode will save the files in a folder named "Virtual Store", at this location: `C:\Users\<login name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\...`. The application will not be aware the file went there. Subsequent reads will read from that Virtual Store location.

It seems vim isn't UAC aware and it is running in compatibility mode - which could be fixed, but as for version 7.4 it hasn't.